# Sum of Joint PMF

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

I have the following question in one of my probability books and I have just picked up studying Joint PMFs but something doesn't seem to add up here.

Let $N$ and $K$ be random variables having the joint PMF:

$$P_{N,K}(n,k)=\begin{cases}
\frac{100^ne^{-100}}{(n+1)!} & k=0,1,2,...,n ; n=0,1,2,...\\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now since this is a joint PMF shouldn't running a double sum give 1? However when I tried running that sum on WolframAlpha I get a conditioned result for the convergence of the sum [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%20n%20equals%200%20to%20infinity%20sum%20from%20k%20equals%200%20to%20n%20e%5E%28-x%29*100%5Ex%2F%28x%2B1%29%21)

Can someone explain what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what's going on:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^n}_{=n+1}\frac{100^ne^{-100}}{(n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{100^ne^{-100}}{n!}=e^{-100}e^{100}=1$$

Comment: Ahhhh
Stupid me, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome @FoundABetterName